# an secure image call unsecure image in avatar wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I have a blog in wordpress and the avatar athor image call an unsecure image and that do my page unsecure.

My page is not secure because Mixed content
[image]

This is the secure image (https://) calling unsecure image (http://), the fourth column in the console is the `initiator`
[image]

this is the bad image because is http and not https
[image]

this is my php code

`<?php if ($abox_avtr_size) { ?>
                <div class="author-img pull-left">
                    <?php echo str_replace( "class='avatar", "class='media-object ".$abox_avtr_style." avatar", get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email'), $abox_avtr_size, null, false, array('scheme' => 'https') ) ); ?>
                </div> <?php } ?>`

PD: I use the let's encrypt certificate

Comment: View page source and check whether the link to the image is http or https. That should give you a better idea at where the problem is.

Comment: I can't found an option to change the images links, but all my links in all pages are https, only the author avatar image is wrong (if I comment author avatar in firefox the page is secure)